# Include related items from another collection into a result set

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

#### TLDR

How do I use MongoDB aggregation to include related documents from another collection that is linked by a one to many relationship?

In essence, what I want to do is to be able to fetch a list of Questions *and include all flags associated with that question*.

**Update (11/07/2016):** Solved with the solution posted below.

**Update (05/07/2016):** I have somewhat managed to get a list of questions with their associated flags by using a combination of `$unwind, $lookup, $project` etc. The updated query is below.

**Problem (05/07/2016):** I am only able to fetch questions that have nested flags. I want to fetch *all* questions even if they do not have any flags.

I have two collections, one for content and one for content flags, as follows:

#### The schema for the content (question collection)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "slug" : "a-sample-title",
    "content" : "Some content.",
    "title" : "A Sample Title.",
    "kind" : "Question",
    "updated" : ISODate("2016-06-08T08:54:26.104Z"),
    "isPublished" : true,
    "isFeatured" : false,
    "flags" : [ 
        ObjectId("<id_of_flag_one>"), 
        ObjectId("<id_of_flag_two>")
    ],
    "answers" : [ 
        ObjectId("..."), 
        ObjectId("...")
    ],
    "related" : [],
    "isAnswered" : true,
    "__v" : 4
}
```

#### The shcema for the flags (flags collection)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "flaggedBy" : ObjectId("<a_users_id>"),
    "type" : "like",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

In the above, a question can have many flags and a flag can only have one question. What I want to do is return all flags for a question when I query the question collection. I have tried doing this using aggregation with some luck.

Here is the *updated* query that I am using (05/07/2016)

```
fetchQuestions: (permission, params) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let query = Question.aggregate([
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'users',
                    localField: 'author',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'authorObject'
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: '$authorObject'
            },
            {
                $unwind: '$flags'
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'flags',
                    localField: 'flags',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'flagObjects'
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: '$flagObjects'
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {
                        _id: '$_id',
                        title: '$title',
                        content: '$content',
                        updated: '$updated',
                        isPublished: '$isPublished',
                        isFeatured: '$isFeatured',
                        isAnswered: '$isAnswered',
                        answers: '$answers',
                        author: '$authorObject'
                    },
                    flags: {
                        $push: '$flags'
                    },
                    flagObjects: {
                        $push: '$flagObjects'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 0,
                    _id: '$_id._id',
                    title: '$_id.title',
                    content: '$_id.content',
                    updated: '$_id.updated',
                    isPublished: '$_id.isPublished',
                    isFeatured: '$_id.isFeatured',
                    author: {
                        fullname: '$_id.author.fullname',
                        username: '$_id.author.username'
                    },
                    flagCount: {
                        $size: '$flagObjects'
                    },
                    answersCount: {
                        $size: '$_id.answers'
                    },
                    flags: '$flagObjects',
                    wasFlagged: {
                        $cond: {
                            if: {
                                $gt: [
                                    {
                                        $size: '$flagObjects'
                                    },
                                    0
                                ]
                            },
                            then: true,
                            else: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    updated: 1
                }
            },
            {
                $skip: 0
            },
            // {
            //     $limit: 110
            // }
        ])
        .exec((error, result) => {
            if(error) reject(error);
            else resolve(result);
        });
    });
},
```

I have tried using other aggregation operators like `$unwind` and `$group` but the result set comes back with five items or less, and I am finding it difficult to grasp the concept of how these should all work together to get me what I need.

This is the response I am getting and it is exactly what I need. The only problem is, as described above, that I am only getting questions that have flags and not all questions.

```
"questions": [
{
  "_id": "5757dd42d0c2ae292f76f11a",
  "flags": [
    {
      "_id": "5774e0a81f2874821f71ace8",
      "flaggedBy": "57569d02d0c2ae292f76f0f5",
      "type": "concern",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "577a0f5414b834372a6ac772",
      "flaggedBy": "5756aa79d0c2ae292f76f0f8",
      "type": "concern",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ],
  "title": "A question for the landing page.",
  "content": "This is a question that will appear on the landing page.",
  "updated": "2016-06-08T08:54:26.104Z",
  "isPublished": true,
  "isFeatured": false,
  "author": {
    "fullname": "Matt Finucane",
    "username": "matfin-386829"
  },
  "flagCount": 2,
  "answersCount": 2,
  "wasFlagged": true
},
...,
...,
...
]
```

Comment: If your MongoDB version is 3.2 or newer then [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: Hmm not sure I understand. I am using $lookup in the aggregation query.

Comment: I can also confirm that I am using MongoDB version 3.2.x

Comment: Why do you have two `$lookup` stage in there? Remove the first `$lookup` stage. Also [`$lookup` does not play well with array field in 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967482/lookup-on-objectids-in-an-array).

Comment: The first $lookup is used to fetch the author of the question so I can use it in my projection later on. From my understanding, this is similar to using something like the populate() function in Mongoose. I amended the aggregated query with the suggestions inside the link you posted and now I have a list of 5 flag objects returned. My question projection is ignored now. How can I write this so that I *nest* the flagObjects inside the result set for my query without changing the output of the query. Am I going down the correct path when using aggregation ?

Comment: The more I think of this and read into it, I think the approach I am trying to take is completely wrong. Will research other ways to do this using Mongoose and report back with any solutions I find.

Comment: There is not between the "foreignField" and the "localField" in the document you've show. That being said the flag document is  `{ "_id" : ObjectId("5774e0a81f2874821f71ace8"), "flaggedBy" : ObjectId("57569d02d0c2ae292f76f0f5"), "type" : "concern", "__v" : 0 }`, the following query gives you the expected result.

`db.contents.aggregate({"$unwind": "$flags" }, {"$lookup": { "from": "flags", "localField": "flags", "foreignField": "_id", "as": "flagObjects" } })`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116187/discussion-between-user3100115-and-matfin).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like I have figured out a solution to this problem which will be posted below.

An overview of the problem I was having was as follows:

- I have a collection of `Questions` with various fields such as title, content, date of posting etc on top of the usual `ObjectID` field.
- I have a separate collection of `Flags` that are related to a question.
- When a Flag is posted for a `Question`, the `ObjectID` of that `Flag` should be added to an array field called `flags` attached to the `Question` document.
- In short, `Flags` are not stored directly inside the `Question` document. A reference to the `Flag` is stored as an `ObjectID`.

What I needed to do was fetch all items from the `Questions` collection **and include the related flags**.

The MongoDB aggregation framework seemed to the ideal solution for this, but getting your head around it can be a bit tricky, especially when dealing with the `$group`, `$lookup` and `$unwind` operators.

I should also point out that I am using `NodeJS v6.x.x` and Mongoose `4.4.x`.

#### This is the (rather large) commented solution to the problem.

```
fetchQuestions: (permission, params) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let query = Question.aggregate([
            /**
             *  We need to perform a lookup on the author 
             *  so we can include the user details for the 
             *  question. This lookup is quite easy to handle 
             *  because a question should only have one author.
             */
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'users',
                    localField: 'author',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'authorObject'
                }
            },
            /**
             *  We need this so that the lookup on the author
             *  object pulls out an author object and not an
             *  array containing one author. This simplifies
             *  the process of $project below.
             */
            {
                $unwind: '$authorObject'
            },
            /**
             *  We need to unwind the flags field, which is an 
             *  array of ObjectIDs. At this stage of the aggregation 
             *  pipeline, questions will be repeated so for example 
             *  if there are two questions and one of them has two 
             *  flags and the other has four flags, the result set 
             *  will have six items and the questions will be repeated
             *  the same number of times as the flags they contain.
             *  The $group function later on will take care of this 
             *  and return only unique questions.
             *
             *  It is important to point out how the $unwind function 
             *  is used here. If we did not specify the preserveNullAndEmptyArrays
             *  parameter then the only questions returned would be those
             *  that have flags. Those without would be skipped.
             */
            {
                $unwind: {
                    path: '$flags',
                    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
                }
            },
            /**
             *  Now that we have the ObjectIDs for the flags from the 
             *  $unwind operation above, we need to perform a lookup on
             *  the flags collection to get our flags. We return these 
             *  with the variable name 'flagObjects' we can use later.
             */
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'flags',
                    localField: 'flags',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'flagObjects'
                }
            },
            /**
             *  We then need to perform another unwind on the 'flagObjects' 
             *  and pass them into the next $group function
             */
            {
                $unwind: {
                    path: '$flagObjects',
                    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
                }
            },
            /**
             *  The next stage of the aggregation pipeline takes all 
             *  the duplicated questions with their flags and the flagObjects
             *  and normalises the data. The $group aggregator requires an _id
             *  property to describe how a question should be unique. It also sets
             *  up some variables that can be used when it comes to the $project
             *  stage of the aggregation pipeline.
             *  the flagObjects property calls on the $push function to add a collection
             *  of flagObjects that were pulled from the $lookup above.
             */
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {
                        _id: '$_id',
                        title: '$title',
                        content: '$content',
                        updated: '$updated',
                        isPublished: '$isPublished',
                        isFeatured: '$isFeatured',
                        isAnswered: '$isAnswered',
                        answers: '$answers',
                        author: '$authorObject'
                    },
                    flagObjects: {
                        $push: '$flagObjects'
                    }
                }
            },
            /**
             *  The $project stage of the pipeline then puts together what the final 
             *  result set should look like when the query is executed. Here we can use
             *  various Mongo functions to reshape the data and create new attributes.
             */
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 0,
                    _id: '$_id._id',
                    title: '$_id.title',
                    updated: '$_id.updated',
                    isPublished: '$_id.isPublished',
                    isFeatured: '$_id.isFeatured',
                    author: {
                        fullname: '$_id.author.fullname',
                        username: '$_id.author.username'
                    },
                    flagCount: {
                        $size: '$flagObjects'
                    },
                    answersCount: {
                        $size: '$_id.answers'
                    },
                    flags: '$flagObjects',
                    wasFlagged: {
                        $cond: {
                            if: {
                                $gt: [
                                    {
                                        $size: '$flagObjects'
                                    },
                                    0
                                ]
                            },
                            then: true,
                            else: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            /**
             *  Then we can sort, skip and limit if needs be.
             */
            {
                $sort: {
                    updated: -1
                }
            },
            {
                $skip: 0
            },
            // {
            //     $limit: 110
            // }
        ]);

        query.exec((error, result) => {
            if(error) reject(error);
            else resolve(result);
        });
    });
},
```

#### And this is a sample of what is returned

```
"questions": [
    {
      "_id": "576a85d68c4333a017083fca",
      "title": "How do I do this?",
      "updated": "2016-06-22T12:34:30.919Z",
      "isPublished": false,
      "isFeatured": false,
      "author": {
        "fullname": "Matt Finucane",
        "username": "matfin-386829"
      },
      "flagCount": 1,
      "answersCount": 0,
      "flags": [
        {
          "_id": "5776541a2e38844428696615",
          "flaggedBy": "5756aa79d0c2ae292f76f0f8",
          "type": "concern",
          "__v": 0
        }
      ],
      "wasFlagged": true
    },
    {
      "_id": "576a85d68c4333a017083fc9",
      "title": "Is this a question?",
      "updated": "2016-06-22T12:34:30.918Z",
      "isPublished": true,
      "isFeatured": false,
      "author": {
        "fullname": "Matt Finucane",
        "username": "matfin-386829"
      },
      "flagCount": 2,
      "answersCount": 0,
      "flags": [
        {
          "_id": "5773ce4ea363e5161ae69e7f",
          "flaggedBy": "5756aa79d0c2ae292f76f0f8",
          "type": "concern",
          "__v": 0
        },
        {
          "_id": "577654382e3884442869661d",
          "flaggedBy": "57569d02d0c2ae292f76f0f5",
          "type": "concern",
          "__v": 0
        }
      ],
      "wasFlagged": true
    }
]
```