# MongoDB's aggregation from nested key returns nothing

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

(**Edit** : this question was edited to better reflect the issue, which might be a little more complicated than the proposed related question.)

Let's say I have these two collections

#### products

```
{
  _id: 'AAAA',
  components: [
    { type: 'foo', items: [
      { itemId: 'item1', qty: 2 },
      { itemId: 'item2', qty: 1 }
    ] },
    { type: 'bar', items: [
      { itemId: 'item3', qty: 8 }
    ] }
  ]
}
```

#### items

```
{
  _id: 'item1',
  name: 'Foo Item'
}
{
  _id: 'item2',
  name: 'Bar Item'
}
{
  _id: 'item3',
  name: 'Buz Item'
}
```

And that I perform this query

```
db['products'].aggregate([
  { $lookup: { 
    from: 'items',
    localField: 'components.items.itemId',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'componentItems'
  } }
]);
```

I get this

```
{
  _id: 'AAAA',
  components: [
    { type: 'foo', items: [
      { itemId: 'item1', qty: 2 },
      { itemId: 'item2', qty: 1 }
    ] }
    { type: 'bar', items: [
      { itemId: 'item3', qty: 8 }
    ] }
  ],
  componentItems: [ ]
}
```

<del>Why doesn't the aggregation read the local field value?</del> How can I retrieve the foreign document without losing my original document structure?

## Edit

I have read the [jira issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-21469) and seen the proposed answer, however I don't know how this applies. This is *not* merely an array, but values from an object, *inside* an array. I am not sure how I can unwind this, and how to put it back together without losing the document structure.

## Edit 2

The problem that I have is that I'm not sure how to group the results back together. With this query :

```
db['products'].aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$components' },
  { $unwind: '$components.items' },
  { $lookup: {
    from: 'items',
    localField: 'components.items.itemId',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'componentsItems'
  } }
]);
```

I get the "correct" result of

```
{ "_id" : "AAAA", "components" : { "type" : "foo", "items" : { "itemId" : "item1", "qty" : 2 } }, "componentsItems" : [ { "_id" : "item1", "name" : "Foo Item" } ] }
{ "_id" : "AAAA", "components" : { "type" : "foo", "items" : { "itemId" : "item2", "qty" : 1 } }, "componentsItems" : [ { "_id" : "item2", "name" : "Bar Item" } ] }
{ "_id" : "AAAA", "components" : { "type" : "bar", "items" : { "itemId" : "item3", "qty" : 8 } }, "componentsItems" : [ { "_id" : "item3", "name" : "Buz Item" } ] }
```

But, while I can unwind `components.items`, I cannot seem to unto this, as `$group` complains that

> "the group aggregate field name 'components.items' cannot be used because $group's field names cannot contain '.'"

```
db['products'].aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$components' },
  { $unwind: '$components.items' },
  { $lookup: {
    from: 'items',
    localField: 'components.items.itemId',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'componentsItems'
  } },
  { "$group": {
    "components.type": "$components.type",
    "components.items": { $push: "$components.items" },
    "componentsItems": { $push: "$componentsItems" }
  } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "components": { $push: "$components" },
    "componentsItems": { $push: "$componentsItems" }
  } }
]);
```

## Edit 3

This query is, thus far, the closest that I found, except that `components` are not grouped back by `type`.

```
db['products'].aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$components' },
  { $unwind: '$components.items' },
  { $lookup: {
    from: 'items',
    localField: 'components.items.itemId',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'componentsItems'
  } },
  { $unwind: '$componentsItems' },
  { $group: {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "components": {
      $push: {
        "type": "$components.type",
        "items": "$components.items"
      }
    },
    "componentsItems": { $addToSet: "$componentsItems" }
  } }
]);
```

**Also**: I am concerned that using `$unwind` and `$group` may affect the order of the `components`, which should be preserved. AFAIK, MongoDB preserve array order when storing documents. I'd hate for this functionality to be broken by the awkwardness of `$lookup`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$lookup on ObjectId's in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967482/lookup-on-objectids-in-an-array)

Comment: @Styvane In my opinion, not quite, no.

Comment: @JohnnyHK edited.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my long and awkward solution :

```
db['products'].aggregate([
  // unwind all... because $lookup cannot work with multi-values
  { $unwind: '$components' },
  { $unwind: '$components.items' },

  // lookup... This is a 1:1 relationship but who cares, right?
  { $lookup: {
    from: 'items',
    localField: 'components.items.itemId',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'componentsItems'
  } },

  // our 1:1 relationship is now an array, so this is required
  // before grouping, so we don't end up with array of arrays
  { $unwind: '$componentsItems' },

  // Group 1: put "components.items" in a temporary array
  //          and filter duplicates from "componentsItems"
  { $group: {
    "_id": {
      "i": "$_id",
      "t": "$components.type"
    },
    "items": {
      $push: "$components.items"
    },
    "componentsItems": { $addToSet: "$componentsItems" }
  } },

  // undo $push...
  { $unwind: "$componentsItems" },

  // Group 2: put everything back together
  { $group: {
    "_id": "$_id.i",
    "items": {
      $push: {
        "type": "$_id.t",
        "items": "$items"
      }
    },
    "componentsItems": { $push: "$componentsItems" }
  } }
]);
```

### Edit

A better solution :

```
db['products'].aggregate([
  // Return document, added a collection of "itemId"
  { $project: {
    "_id": 1,
    "components": 1,
    "componentItemId": "$components.items.itemId"
  } },
  // Since there was two arrays, the field is an array of arrays...
  { $unwind: "$componentItemId" },
  { $unwind: "$componentItemId" },

  // make 1:1 lookup...
  { $lookup: {
    from: 'items',
    localField: 'componentItemId',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'componentsItems'
  } },
  // ... extract the 1:1 reference...
  { $unwind: "$componentsItems" },

  // group back, ignoring the "componentItemId" field
  { $group: {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "components": { $first: "$components" },
    "componentItems": { $addToSet: "$componentsItems" }
  }}
]);
```

I'm not sure if there is *yet* a better solution, and I *am* concerned about performance, but this seems to be the only solutions I can think of.

The downside is that documents cannot be dynamic, and this query will need to be modified whenever the schema changes.

## Update

This seems [to be resolved](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22881) in MongoDB 3.3.4 (not release at the time of writing this answer).