# MongoDb $lookup query with multiple fields from objects array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-aggregation

This question has previously been marked as a duplicate of [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967482/lookup-on-objectids-in-an-array) I can with certainty confirm that it is not.

This is not a duplicate of the linked question because the elements in question are not an array but embedded in individual objects of an array as fields. I am fully aware of how the query in the linked question should work, however that scenario is different from mine.

I have a question regarding the `$lookup` query of MongoDb. My data structure looks as follows:

My **"Event"** collection contains this single document:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("mongodbobjectid..."),
   "name": "Some Event",
   "attendees": [
        {
           "type": 1,
           "status": 2,
           "contact": ObjectId("mongodbobjectidHEX1")
        },
        {
           "type": 7,
           "status": 4,
           "contact": ObjectId("mongodbobjectidHEX2")
        }
    ]
}
```

My **"Contact"** collection contains these documents:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("mongodbobjectidHEX1"),
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 35
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("mongodbobjectidHEX2"),
    "name": "Peter Pan",
    "age": 60
}
```

What I want to do is perform an `aggregate` query with the `$lookup` operator on the **"Event"** collection and get the following result with full "contact" data:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("mongodbobjectid..."),
   "name": "Some Event",
   "attendees": [
        {
           "type": 1,
           "status": 2,
           "contact": {
              "_id": ObjectId("mongodbobjectidHEX1"),
              "name": "John Doe",
              "age": 35
           }
        },
        {
           "type": 7,
           "status": 4,
           "contact": {
              "_id": ObjectId("mongodbobjectidHEX2"),
              "name": "Peter Pan",
              "age": 60
           }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have done the same with single elements of "Contact" referenced in another document but never when embedded in an array. I am **unsure of which pipeline arguments to pass** to get the above shown result?

I also want to add a `$match` query to the pipeline to filter the data, but that is not really part of my question.

Comment: Just to clarify, I marked it as duplicate because the answers in that dupe still apply to your question; you need to apply the `$unwind` pipeline to flatten the array of embedded documents for you to apply the `$lookup` operator on the "attendees.contact" field and then after the `$lookup`, pipe another `$unwind` and `$group` the resulting docs to get your desired output. The other answer also applies if you are using the upcoming MongoDB 3.4

Comment: Okay, so what you are saying is that I should first `{"$unwind": "$attendees"}`, then `{ "$lookup" : {"from" : "Contact", "localField" : "attendees.contact","foreignField": "_id", "as" : "contactlist" }}`, then  `{"$unwind": "$contactlist"}` and then `$group`?

Comment: Correct. A tip on debugging a pipeline; run the aggregation query at each pipeline stage, test whether the results tally for each step. So for example, in the aggregation above, first run `db.event.aggregate([ { "$unwind": "$attendees" } ]);` , check the result to see if the attendees array is deconstructed properly, add the next pipeline stage `db.event.aggregate([ { "$unwind": "$attendees" },{ "$lookup" : {"from" : "Contact", "localField" : "attendees.contact","foreignField": "_id", "as" : "contactlist" }} ]);`, run that and repeat the steps till you get to the final pipeline step.

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to debug it to the last $unwind step and everything seems correct. At that stage the query on the "Events" collection which holds 1 document returns 2 documents (because of 2 attendees), each having a field "contactList" with the data of one contact. Would that be the expected outcome? Now I am unsure how to group this result to get the output described above

Comment: Yes, that's expected because of the initial `{"$unwind": "$attendees"}` pipeline where for each input document, it outputs `n` documents where `n` is the number of array elements and can be zero for an empty array. You can safely group all these documents by the main `_id` field i.e. `{ "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id", "name": { "$first": "$name" },
        "attendees": { "$push": "$contactlist" } } }`

Comment: Thank you, that worked, really appreciate your help. I just had to modify your last "group" command a little bit: `"attendees" : { "$push": {"contact": "$contactlist"}}` to get the "contact" field. I suppose that should be fine. My last problem is that "type" and "status" of the attendee are not yet present in my output, how can I get  those included in the output as well?

Comment: Thanks. The $first with the "name" worked fine, however "name" is related to "Event" whereas "type" and "status" are related to the individual "attendees". The query you mentioned adds a field "type" and "status" only to my "event", but of course not to the "attendees". Is there a way to map type and status to the individual attendees?

Comment: Do the same with the `name` field, use the [**`$first`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first) operator as 
`{ 
 "$group": { 
  "_id": "$_id", 
  "name": { "$first": "$name" }, , 
  "attendees": { 
   "$push": { 
    "type": "$attendees.type",
    "status": "$attendees.status", 
    "contact": "$contactlist" 
   } 
  } 
 } 
}`

Comment: Thank you again for the effort, that is the correct answer. I will create a post and answer below.

Comment: In case you are not tired of me yet, I'd really appreciate if you take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635501/mongodb-aggregation-query-with-group-and-push-into-subdocument :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 db.getCollection('Event').aggregate([{ "$unwind": "$attendees" },
        { "$lookup" : { "from" : "Contact", "localField" : "attendees.contact", "foreignField": "_id", "as" : "contactlist" } },
        { "$unwind": "$contactlist" },
         { "$project" :{
                    "attendees.type" : 1,
                    "attendees.status" : 1,
                    "attendees.contact" : "$contactlist",
                      "name": 1, "_id": 1
                       }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                _id : "$_id" ,
                "name" : { $first : "$name" }, 
                "attendees" : { $push : "$attendees" }
            }
        }
        ])
```

Comment: This query returns the desired output, but the Documents in the returned in the "attendees" array have no fields (contact, type, ... are missing). Do you know what might cause this?

Comment: Can you tell me what you got with this query?

Comment: you shouldn't unwind contactlist array otherwise you will miss the other parts and it will return the 0 index of array