# $lookup for foreignField from an Embedded Document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 2 collections say, Collection-1, and Collection-2.

```
Collection-1
{
"_id" : 1,
"myArray" : [ { Key : "KeyVal", price:40 } ] 
}
Collection-2
{
"_id" : 1,
"myArray" : [ { Key : "KeyVal", quantity:20 } ] 
}
```

What I am trying is i would like to multiply price and quantity from collection-1 and 2.

To do this, I am joining both the collections using `$lookup`. 
I could able to `$unwind` the Collection-1 to get the key. The Question is How do I get the Key (foreign Key) from the collection 2?

Am I making fundamental mistakes? Suggestions please. Also please share the link if related question is already asked .

**Note: The most important concern is i can't change the collection structure. otherwise i could have make the key as _id and i can proceed further.**

Comment: What's your MongoDB server version?

Comment: its 3.2..   Does latest version supports?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36647133/122005) should be helpful.