# Using $lookup on an array of objects to join two documents in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have many `Shop` documents that each contain a field `products` which is an array of objects where the key is the product ID and the value is the quantity in stock:

`{ products: [{"a": 3}, {"b": 27}, {"c": 4}] }`

I have a collection `Products` where each product has a document containing `productId`, `name`, etc:

`{ productId: "a", "name": "Spanner"}`

I would like to pull in/aggregate/join the product information for each of those items. I know how to do it when the field is a single ID, and I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967482/lookup-on-objectids-in-an-array) which describes how to do it for an array of IDs. But I am having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around what to do with an array of objects containing IDs.

Desired output:

```
{
    products: [
        { {productId: "a", "name": "Spanner"}: 3 }
    ]
}
```

(And no, it is not within my control to switch to a relational database.)

Comment: If the downvoter could please explain how I can improve this question, that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think if you want to using ID for reference, try to avoid place it as object keys, instead make it as object property like { products: [{"productId": $_id, "quantity": 3}]}, that could be a reason for downvote.

But if you cant change it, you can using [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) in aggregation to convert your array.

One more thing, your desire output is unreal because object property in js cant not be an object.

Try it:

```
db.Shop.aggregate(

// Pipeline
[
    // Stage 1
    {
        $unwind: {
            path : "$products"
        }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
        $project: {
            products: { $objectToArray: "$products" }
        }
    },

    // Stage 3
    {
        $unwind: {
            path : "$products"
        }
    },

    // Stage 4
    {
        $project: {
            productId: "$products.k",
            productQuantity: "$products.v"
        }
    },

    // Stage 5
    {
        $lookup: {
            "from" : "products",
            "localField" : "productId",
            "foreignField" : "productId",
            "as" : "products"
        }
    },

    // Stage 6
    {
        $unwind: {
            path : "$products"
        }
    },

    // Stage 7
    {
        $project: {
            productId: "$productId",
            productQuantity: "$productQuantity",
            productName: "$products.name"
        }
    },
]);
```

Good luck

Comment: Thank you. However, even if I change to the format you suggest, my problem is that I am not sure how to access the properties inside each object (so, the `productId`). Sorry if that I was not clear.

Comment: you can access object property by $products.productId