# How to do lookup with an array in mongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

today I started working with MongoDB. I have created two collections: Restaurant and OpeningHours. I have inserted data to the database with the following code:

```
   db.OpeningHours.insert({
        day: "Sunday",
        from: "10.00am",
        to: "16.00pm"
});

    db.Restaurant.insert({
         name: "Restaurant01",
         openingHoursId: 
           [
             {id: db.OpeningHours.find({day: "Sunday", from: "10.00am", to: "16.00pm"})[0]._id},
           ]
});
```

The restaurant contains an array of OpeningHours ids. I want to write a query with lookup so I get all the data from the Restaurant and the data for corresponding opening hours. Here is my code so far and if I run it I get an error: Command failed...

```
db.Restaurant.aggregate([
{
    $unwind: "$openingHoursId",
    $lookup:
        {
            from: "OpeningHours",
            localField: "id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "RestaurantHours"
        }
}
])
```

The expected result I want is something like this:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5c43b6c8d0fa3ff24621f749"),
   "name": "Restaurant01",
   "openingHoursId": 
          [
              {
                 "id": ObjectId("5c43b6c8d0fa3ff2462fg93e")
              }
          ],
   "RestaurantHours" :
          [ 
              {
                  "_id": ObjectId("5c43b6c8d0fa3ff2462fg93e"),
                  "day": "Sunday",
                  "from": "10.00am",
                  "to": "16.00pm"  
              }
          ]
}
```

Comment: This one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967482/lookup-on-objectids-in-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `localField` should be `openingHoursId.id` not only `id`

```
db.Restaurant.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$openingHoursId" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "OpeningHours",
    "localField": "openingHoursId.id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "openingHoursId.RestaurantHours"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$openingHoursId.RestaurantHours" },
  { "$group": { 
    "_id": "$_id",
    "name": { "$first": "name" },
    "openingHoursId": { "$push": "openingHoursId" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I and more ids to the openingHoursId array the results won't be pushed into the same array. For example if I add two more ids into the array (total = 3) then the result will print out the same restaurant three times but every iteration it will change the array element