# mongodb joining two table with multiple array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have one table membership and another is promo codes.

**membership table:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b62e7050b13587e9febb8db"),
    "country_id" : "5a093507f1d45633844096ef",
    "type" : "Bronze",
    "price" : "30",
}
/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6961175140b477032291b7"),
    "country_id" : "5a093507f1d45633844096ef",
    "type" : "Gold",
    "price" : "1000",
}....
```

**promo code table :**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cfe23fd075be65883f6d921"),
    "final_status" : 1,
    "membership" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b62e7050b13587e9febb8db"), 
        ObjectId("5b6961175140b477032291b7"), 
        ObjectId("5b6961285140b477032291b8"), 
        ObjectId("5b7567dd5b874856981b53d3"), 
        ObjectId("5bba1c3794c6761db256edbc")
    ],
    "month" : [ 
        "1", 
        "3"
    ]
}
```

**here, the promomcode table has a membership id. I want promo code data with membership join query.get promo code data with membership detail
Please help me**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$lookup on ObjectId's in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967482/lookup-on-objectids-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $lookup for left outer join in mongodb

```js
db.promocode.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'membership',
    localField: 'membership',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'memberships'
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    membership: 0
  }
}])
```