# $lookup on ObjectId's in an array does not work

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, lookup

i have the same case as in this question: [$lookup on ObjectId's in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967482/lookup-on-objectids-in-an-array) (i can't comment on the question since i don't have enough reputation... sorry for the duplication..) - but 
the query doesn't work for me and i get an empty array in the end of it.

i want to get a list of companies with a field of its positions, but the positions field is always empty
on the following code. (i get the company fields, and with the $unwind - even the company fields are not returned).

what am i doing wrong?

mongoose version: 5.7.14
mongodb version:  4.2.3

i also tried a lot of combinations of aggregation and populate and none of them succeeded.

```
const schema = new Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    positionsIds: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'Position',
      require: false
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Company', schema);

-----------------------------

const schema = new Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    requirements: [{
      years: { type: Number, required: false },
      skill: { type: String, required: false },
    }],
    companyId: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'Company',
      required: true
    },
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Position', schema );

---------------------------

    let companies = await Company.aggregate([
      { 
        $lookup: 
        { 
          from: 'Position',
          localField: '_id',
          foreignField: 'companyId',
          as: 'positions' 
        }  
      },
      // {
      //     $unwind: '$positions' // - mess the query even more and return an empty array
      // },
      ]);
```

Comment: Did you try: `from: 'positions'` ?

Comment: no.. tried now and it works! do you know why it made a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongoose creates MongoDB collections based on convention. `Position` as model name gets [translated](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) into plural form `positions` so your query should look like:

```
{ 
    $lookup: { 
        from: 'positions',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'companyId',
        as: 'positions' 
    }  
}
```

> The first argument is the singular name of the collection your model is for. ** Mongoose automatically looks for the plural, lowercased version of your model name. ** Thus, for the example above, the model Tank is for the tanks collection in the database.